# Load image from webmethod

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms, ascx

I used to work in an mvc project and I had used the following code to load an image:

**cshtml**

```
 <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", new { imageUrl =
 @asset.ImageUrl })" />
```

**C#**

```
public void GetImage(string imageUrl )
        {

            try
            {
                using (WebClientExtension client1 = new WebClientExtension())
                {
                    byte[] imageBytes = client1.ExecuteRequest(imageUrl );
                    if (imageBytes.Count() == 0)
                        throw new Exception();
                    HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                    HttpContext.Response.OutputStream.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                String FilePath;
                FilePath = Server.MapPath("/Images/no_image.png");
                byte[] imageBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
                HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                HttpContext.Response.OutputStream.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            }

        }
```

Everything worked fine, and now my problem is use this in an ascx page. Obviously,`@Url.Action("GetRenditionImage", new { renditionUrl =
     @asset.RenditionUrl })` wont work in ascx. How can I call a web method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use @Url.Action. Use simple:

```
<img src="GetImage?imageUrl=sampleUrl" />
```

Comment: Well, unlike mvc, I had to specify the entire path to the webmethod than only the action name. Thankz :)